# AWS SNS mobile notification not working

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-sns, boto3

```
snsclient = boto3.client('sns')
num = random.randrange(1000, 9999, 4)
res = snsclient.publish(
    # TopicArn='arn:aws:sns:us-east-1:841538128291:MySNSTopic',
    # TargetArn='string',
    PhoneNumber='phone number',
    Message='Your random 4 digit password is : ' + str(num),
    # Subject='string',
    # MessageStructure='string',
    # MessageAttributes={
    # 'string': {
    #   'DataType': 'string',
    #  'StringValue': 'string',
    # 'BinaryValue': 'bytes'
    # }
    # }
)
```

i'm not getting the sms by this in aws lambda function.
for this i am using the python boto3 library for amazon web services.

when i am using this code in other lambda function it works fine but in a main lambda function for my alexa skill it doesn't works.

Comment: What lambda function are you speaking about?

Comment: amazon lambda function of AWS

Comment: I don't understand what you call an "Amazon Lambda function". Can you explain? This has nothing to do with [Python lambda functions](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/controlflow.html#lambda-expressions), right?

Comment: **AWS Lambda Function** is service provided by amazon web services.AWS Lambda is a compute service where you can upload your code to AWS Lambda and the service can run the code on your behalf using AWS infrastructure. After you upload your code and create what we call a Lambda function, AWS Lambda takes care of provisioning and managing the servers that you use to run the code.

Comment: Ok, It's clear now. It's like stored procedures in database. For your problem, have you tried to turn the logging in debug mode? Boto3 is verbose and can help you to find out what's wrong.

Answer (score 0):

I have tested your code successfully as illustrated below and I don't see this issue originating from the code snippet provided:

```
import boto3
import random

session = boto3.Session(profile_name = 'syumaK')
snsclient = session.client(
    'sns',
    region_name='us-east-1'
)

num = random.randrange(1000, 9999, 4)
response = snsclient.publish(
   #TopicArn='arn:aws:sns:us-east-1:19250632XXXX:SNS-Topic',
   #TargetArn='string',
   PhoneNumber="+27780041078",
   Message='Your random 4 digit password is : ' + str(num)
   # Subject='string',
   # MessageStructure='string',
   # MessageAttributes={
   # 'string': {
   #   'DataType': 'string',
   #  'StringValue': 'string',
   # 'BinaryValue': 'bytes'
   # }
   # }
)

print()
print(response)
print()
```

[Click here to view the delivery success](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ahNt2.png)

Recommendation:

- The best way to find out why the SNS SMS messages are failing is by enabling  [SNS SMS CloudWatch delivery logs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sns/latest/dg/sms_stats_cloudwatch.html).